# Ember.js bindings not firing changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an container object that holds 3 items. Each of that item has some text fields (eg: text1, text2, text3, text4). Besides that I also have a computed property that returns the current item based on a property called currentItemIndex.

So, basically, this is the 'item model':

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
    text1: null,
    text2: null,
    text3: null,
    text4: null
});
```

This is the computed property

```
App.currentItemIndex = 0;
App.currentItem = function () {
    return App.containerObject[App.get('currentItemIndex')];
}.property('App.currentItemIndex');
```

And a mock datasource could look like this:

```
App.containerObject.pushObject(App.Item.create({text1:'Text 1', text2:'Text 2', text3:'Text 3', text4:'Text 4'}));
App.containerObject.pushObject(App.Item.create({text1:'Text 1', text2:'Text 2', text3:'Text 3', text4:'Text 4'}));
App.containerObject.pushObject(App.Item.create({text1:'Text 1', text2:'Text 2', text3:'Text 3', text4:'Text 4'}));
```

So, as you can see each item has the same text values and when I'm changing App.currentItemIndex to any value 0, 1 or 2 **the binding won't trigger the notification that something has changed.**, because of course the properties did not changed but the object is a new one.

So the question is:
**How can I force to trigger this notification to update the views accordingly?**

Answer (score 2):

I wonder how do you change the value of `App.currentItemIndex`. You have to use the set method here, like:

```
 App.set('currentItemIndex', 1)
```

Note that you can use `App.containerObject.objectAt(App.get('currentItemIndex'))` instead of accessing `App.containerObject[App.get('currentItemIndex')]`

EDIT: Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/c4bA2/69/

I'm always using the get/set to access properties, and declare them inside the application.

Comment: Yes, I'm using App.set('currentItemIndex', anyNumber) to set the index of course :), and I also know about the objectAt method. But this doesn't help.

Comment: This only happens if I use the same text values for those items, if I use different values, then it will detect the change and trigger the event.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem now :)

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, apparently the problem is somewhere with Twitter Bootstrap Button plugin. I think I'm not using something well.

Comment: In fact, when using $(#btnId).button("loading") I think you are breaking the Ember's metamorph system. At least it destroys the view, and then when the notfication is triggered, there is an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18434/discussion-between-artur-and-sly7-7)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arturgrigor/c4bA2/86/)

The problem was caused by the `removeClass('btn-success btn-danger')` call. This is weird because on [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) it says that you can remove multiple classes at a time.

So, if I just use `removeClass('btn-success')` or `removeClass('btn-danger')` then everything works fine.